# Merge two arrays by adding their values

Tags: php, arrays

So I have two arrays and I want to merge them into one array by adding the values with the same key together.

```
array &a
    Array
    (
        [0] => 4
        [1] => 10
        [2] => 3
        [3] => 10
        [4] => 7
    )
  array &b
    Array
    (
        [0] => 
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 2
        [3] => 2
        [4] => 2

    )
```

I expect the resulting array as

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => 4
        [1] => 11
        [2] => 5
        [3] => 12
        [4] => 9

    )
```

Comment: The new array i need to have the same keys - while counting both arrays values

Comment: And what have you tried so far ? just loop through the longest array and add the values...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below code:-

```
$a = [4,10,3,10,7];
$b = ['',1,2,2,2];

$res = [];
foreach($a as $k=>$v){
   $res[] = $v + $b[$k]; 
}
echo '<pre>'; print_r($res);
```

**output:-**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 11
    [2] => 5
    [3] => 12
    [4] => 9
)
```

If second array $b has no similar numbers of record as first array $a then,

```
$a = [4,10,3,10,7];
$b = ['',1,2,2];  // removed last record

$res = [];
foreach($a as $k=>$v){
   $res[] = $v + (!empty($b[$k]) ? $b[$k] : 0); 
}
echo '<pre>'; print_r($res);
```

**output**:-

```
Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 11
    [2] => 5
    [3] => 12
    [4] => 7
)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can loop through both arrays with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) at the same time. And then you just have to add both elements together and return it back as a new element.

Code

```
$result = array_map(function($v1, $v2){
    return $v1 + $v2;
}, $a, $b);
```